# Prometheus: migrate existing data to remote storage CrateDB

Tags: prometheus, cratedb

I have a Prometheus server which has scraped data with 30d of retention policy.

Now I have installed another new Prometheus server but this one is using remote storage with CrateDB.

I want to keep the existing data collected from first server, so I want to migrate that data to the new server. So I created an snapshot and restored it in new server.

But the restored data is not migrated automatically by the crate_adapter to CrateDB database.

So my question is:

how can I do to migrate existing restored data in the new remote storage CrateDB?

The new Promethues server can list restored metrics because they are locally in the server, but I want metrics are in CrateDB so I dont loose that data when retention policy applies.

Thanks.